# R.matlab package appears corrupted

Tags: r, matlab, package

Solution: The package R.oo used by R.matlab has a function called getDate. I was loading --another function getDate() before loading the R.matlab package.

---

I can't load the R package R.matlab
Anyone has the same issue? I have the following error message:

```
Loading required package: R.matlab
Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : invalid 'tz' value
Error: package 'R.matlab' could not be loaded
```

Edit: it happens since the last update on 3rd of Feb 2011

```
> sessionInfo()    
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)    
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)    
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252           LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] grDevices datasets  splines   graphics  stats     tcltk     utils     methods   base     
other attached packages: [1] R.oo_1.7.5                   R.methodsS3_1.2.1            waveslim_1.6.4               timeDate_2130.91             ncdf_1.6.5                   rgl_0.92.798                
 [7] fields_6.3                   spam_0.23-0                  splancs_2.01-27              sp_0.9-76                    maps_2.1-5                   shapefiles_0.6              
[13] foreign_0.8-41               scrapeR_0.1.6                XML_3.2-0.2                  mFilter_0.1-3                RCurl_1.5-0.1                bitops_1.0-4.1              
[19] outliers_0.14                chron_2.3-39                 lmtest_0.9-27                PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.3.2 RODBC_1.3-2                  quantmod_0.3-15             
[25] TTR_0.20-2                   xts_0.7-5                    zoo_1.6-4                    Defaults_1.1-1               rcom_2.2-3.1                 rscproxy_1.3-1              
[31] svSocket_0.9-51              TinnR_1.0.3                  R2HTML_2.2                   Hmisc_3.8-3                  survival_2.36-2             
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] cluster_1.13.2  grid_2.12.1     lattice_0.19-17 svMisc_0.9-61   tools_2.12.1
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide sessionInfo()?

Comment: It is quite possible -- but you should rather write to the package author.

Comment: What is the value of your TZ environment variable?

Comment: Anyway who wants to use matlab code when you have R?

Comment: @Fred Presumably the desire is to use MATLAB algorithms without having to write MATLAB code!

Comment: :) was just kidding

> Sys.getenv("TZ")    
   TZ     
"GMT"

Comment: Try deleting that environment variable and then starting R. For example from a cmd.exe window type `set TZ=` to delete it and then immediately run `rterm.exe` or `rgui.exe` to start up R with this environment variable missing.

Comment: I've had problems similar to this with the `TZ` variable in the past.

Comment: Or remove `TZ` from within R if that is easier: `Sys.unsetenv("TZ")`

Comment: I need the TZ has I do a lot of time manipulations in different tz...

Comment: Rather then marking the question as [solved] please accept the correct answer by clicking on the checkmark under the voting arrows (or provide one if the current one is not satisfactory, and accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The package R.oo used by R.matlab has a function called getDate. I was loading --another function getDate() before loading the R.matlab package.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an issue with R.matlab, but with something else. I see that it says "loading required package: R.matlab" , so the command came from somewhere else.

```
> library(R.matlab)
Loading required package: R.oo
Loading required package: R.methodsS3
R.methodsS3 v1.2.1 (2010-09-18) successfully loaded. See ?R.methodsS3 for help.
R.oo v1.7.5 (2011-02-01) successfully loaded. See ?R.oo for help.
R.matlab v1.3.7 (2011-02-01) successfully loaded. See ?R.matlab for help.
```

On Windows 7, R 2.12.1.

Please provide the full detail of the command you used that loaded R.matlab. And you might want to post this on the R-help list or R-devel list, this seems to be a bug of some kind. It's always a good idea to put the package maintainer in cc, so they know.

Session info :

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
 [1] grid      grDevices datasets  splines   graphics  stats     tcltk     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] R.matlab_1.3.7     R.oo_1.7.5         R.methodsS3_1.2.1  reshape_0.8.3      plyr_1.2.1         gplots_2.8.0      
 [7] caTools_1.11       bitops_1.0-4.1     gdata_2.8.1        gtools_2.6.2       RColorBrewer_1.0-2 chron_2.3-39      
[13] xlsReadWrite_1.5.3 svSocket_0.9-51    TinnR_1.0.3        R2HTML_2.2         Hmisc_3.8-3        survival_2.36-2   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] cluster_1.13.2  lattice_0.19-13 svMisc_0.9-61   tools_2.12.1
```

Comment: @Fred : but then you use it from within a script? That's also important information. Try from the command line and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @ Joris Meys: indeed works fine on a new R console. I have to dig into my source files to see with command make the loading of R.matlab crash. I love open source software but sometimes........